# Web3 - Cannot read property 'clearSubscriptions' of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, ganache

While creating a web3 instance, and attempting to call `setProvider` with a valid provider (Ganache), I get a TypeError.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearSubscriptions' of undefined`

Steps to reproduce the error

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");      
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(ganache.provider());    //The error occurs at this point
```

My Ganache is successfully running on `localhost:12345` with 10 accounts, each having 100 eth.

My dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "async":             "^2.6.2",
    "bignumber":         "^1.1.0",
    "bignumber.js":      "^2.4.0",
    "command-line-args": "^2.1.6",
    "ethereumjs-abi":    "^0.6.7",
    "fs":                "0.0.2",
    "ganache-cli":       "^6.4.3",
    "js-sha256":         "^0.3.2",
    "request":           "^2.88.0",
    "solc":              "^0.5.4",
    "web3":              "^1.0.0-beta.55"
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. It does not look like a dependency issue. Can you please add the entire Javascript code. Also the complete error log. Thank you

Comment: That's the only JavaScript code. Nothing else. To reproduce, do `npm init` and then add the dependencies in package.json file. Then do `npm install` and try to run `node app.js`. Also, before that you need to start Ganache with `ganache-cli --port 12345`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the app.js file?

Comment: Let me simplify it for you. 1. I started a local Ganache blockchain. 2. Now I want to use get all the accounts of Ganache using web3. For that I am trying to set web3 as the provider

Comment: There were some issues with recent beta versions of web3, try with beta34 or beta37.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to list out the accounts from ganache, you can use

```js
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

getAccounts = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(accounts);
};
getAccounts();
```

I have followed your steps to create the node project, except that I have not started ganache-cli seperately using the `ganache-cli --port 12345` command.

Comment: After this, when I try to compile using solidity, it throws an error - `ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.`

Comment: Your solidity code should have the first line `pragma solidity ^<version>;` Try compiling in remix first